# Python - PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

My script searches for all the pdf files in a specific directory and then extracts an id from the pdf and organise the pdfs within the files.  For example I have:

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\aa\1.pdf, with id = 3,
C:\Users\user\Downloads\aa\2.pdf, with id = 5,
C:\Users\user\Downloads\aa\3.pdf, with id = 10
```

and I want to organize them like this:

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\aa\3\1.pdf
C:\Users\user\Downloads\aa\5\2.pdf
C:\Users\user\Downloads\aa\10\3.pdf
```

The following script does the job, but I think only for the last file outputs  the following error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\aa\project.py", line 74, in 
    os.rename(source, dest)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\aa\3.pdf' -> 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\aa\10\3.pdf'**

```
 import PyPDF2
 import re
 import glob, os
 import shutil
 import sys
 from collections import Counter
 from collections import defaultdict

 class DictList(dict):
     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
         try:
             self[key].append(value)
         except KeyError:
             super(DictList, self).__setitem__(key, value)
         except AttributeError:
             super(DictList, self).__setitem__(key, [self[key], value])

 files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\aa\*.pdf')

 gesi_id=[]
 dic = DictList()

 c = 0

 for i in files:   
     pdfFileObj = open(files[c],'rb')
     pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
     num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
     count = 0
     text = ""

 while count < num_pages:
     pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
     count +=1
     text += pageObj.extractText()

 keywords = []
 keywords = re.findall(r'[0-9]\w+', text); 
 gesi_id.append(keywords[0])
 key = str(gesi_id[c])
 value = files[c]
 dic[key] = value
 c=c+1

 gesi_id_unique = []
 for x in gesi_id: 
         if x not in gesi_id_unique: 
             gesi_id_unique.append(x) 

 c=0
 if not gesi_id_unique:
   sys.exit()

 for i in gesi_id_unique:
     dirName = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\aa\\', 
 str(gesi_id_unique[c]))
     c=c+1

     if not os.path.exists(dirName):
         os.mkdir(dirName)

 keys = list(dic)
 values = list(dic.values())
 k = 0
 v = 0
 for i in keys:
     for val in values[k]:
         source = val


          dest = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\aa\\', 
 gesi_id_unique[k],  val.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1])
         print(gesi_id_unique[k])
         print(val.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1])
         print("Source: %s"  % source)
         print("Dest: %s" % dest)
          os.rename(source, dest)
     k = k+1
```

Comment: I see a  call to `open` but where do you close the file?

Comment: maybe it is used by another program such as acrobat PDF reader. I had the same issue when a CSV file was open in excel at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think that due to copy and past some indentations got disturbed, In fact there's a part that should be :

```
for i in files:   
     pdfFileObj = open(files[c],'rb')
     pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
     num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
     count = 0
     text = ""

     while count < num_pages:
          pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
          count +=1
          text += pageObj.extractText()

      keywords = []
      keywords = re.findall(r'[0-9]\w+', text); 
      gesi_id.append(keywords[0])
      key = str(gesi_id[c])
      value = files[c]
      dic[key] = value
      c=c+1
```

And to solve the problem you just need to close the currectly used file by adding `pdfFileObj.close()` at the in of this that it becomes :

```
for i in files:   
     pdfFileObj = open(files[c],'rb')
     pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
     num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
     count = 0
     text = ""

     while count < num_pages:
          pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
          count +=1
          text += pageObj.extractText()

      keywords = []
      keywords = re.findall(r'[0-9]\w+', text); 
      gesi_id.append(keywords[0])
      key = str(gesi_id[c])
      value = files[c]
      dic[key] = value
      c=c+1
      pdfFileObj.close()
```

Comment: It seems to work, but when i have another file and run the script for second time with name 5.pdf and id = 3, I have this error:  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C' -> 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\aa\\3\\C                               It seems to get only the "C" from the val value for source

Comment: Simply because this PDF doesn't contain written text. Instead, It contains images containing texts.